# how to call a function in v-if mine is not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a vue file where template is coded like this.

```
<template>
<div class="pull-right">
    <i class="fa fa-circle green" v-if="checkUser()"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle red" v-else></i>
</div>
</template>
```

And the Script is like this.

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['user', 'onlineusers'],
    methods: {
        checkUser: function(){
            var online = false;
            var status =  _.find(this.onlineusers ,{id: this.user.id});
            if(status != undefined)
            {
                online = true
            }

            return online;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I also tried like this.

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['user', 'onlineusers'],
    methods: {
        checkUser: function(){
           return _.find(this.onlineusers ,{id: this.user.id});

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

But Nothing is working. I am new at VUE. Can anyone help ?

Update: In the app.js file where the getting data about online users.

```
  if(fromId != 'null'){

        Echo.join('Online')
            .here((users) => {
                this.onlineUsers = users;
            })
            .joining((user) => {
                this.onlineUsers.push(user);
            })
            .leaving((user) => {
                this.onlineUsers = this.onlineUsers.filter((u) => {u != user});
            })
    }
```

This is onlineuser tag.

```
   <onlineuser v-bind:user="{{$user}}" v-bind:onlineusers="onlineUsers"></onlineuser>
```

Comment: did you get some errors ?

Comment: weirdly NO. And I can find the object I wanted to. All working fine except the <i> tags are not switching.

Comment: please provide the structure of  `onlineusers` property

Comment: https://prnt.sc/la27cr 
here is the screen short of onlineusers

Comment: i see that  user doesn't have id property

Comment: Can you try to write `debugger` on the line before the return? Then In dev-tools, see in the scoped tab to see what online is

Comment: it does. Just not in the screen shot. http://prntscr.com/la2aid Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @SølveTornøe Actually I used console.log to check that I can get one true and 6 false as I have 7 users and one is online. But the <i> tag doesn't switch

Comment: Your markup is correct, so there must be an issue inside your function. Have you tried to log inside the if statement to see that it runs once? (Since you had 6 offline and 1 online user)

Comment: Yes I did. As I said. I can get the expected values in the functions. But The v-if is not getting them god knows why.

Answer (score 0):

```
<i class="fa fa-circle green" v-if="checkUser"></i>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['user', 'onlineusers'],
    computed: {
      checkUser(){
        return _.find(this.onlineusers ,{id: this.user.id});
      }
    }
    }
}
</script>
```

Can you try using computed property like above.

Comment: There was an extra } (braket) here. If I remove it. It complies but same as before. Do not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <template>
      <div class="pull-right">
      <i class="fa fa-circle green" v-if="online"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-circle red" v-else></i>
    </div>
   </template>

   <script>
    export default {
    props: ['user', 'onlineusers'],
    computed: {
        online (){
           return this.onlineusers.find(user => user.id == this.user.id);
         }
       }
     }
   </script>
```

Comment: gives me this error in console
this.onlineusers.find is not a function

Comment: What is `this.onlineusers`?

Comment: It's an Array of Objects

Answer (score 0):

checkUser of yours is returning a boolean, not an iterable item.

You have to return something vue can loop on.

Comment: what do mean by iterable item?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Something you can iterate ~ loop on. For example, an array

Comment: if you mean an array or an object, it will be cast to true if it's not empty

Comment: I don't understand. I tried to set boolean. It's didn't work. If I return the object it also didn't work. But If I set true instead of checkUser() it works fine. but that's hard coded.

Comment: LOL, I'm too tired for stackoverflow today.. I thought it was a v-for 

Comment: @SølveTornøe Lol :)